# Fixed Point Arithmetic in Chisel HDL

Tags: scala, hdl, fixed-point, chisel

Are there any fixed point libraries in Chisel HDL which could be used to perform basic arithmetic operations such as add, subtract, multiply and divide?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a Fixed class is under active development.  Take a look at [Fixed.scala](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel/blob/master/src/main/scala/Fixed.scala) in the Chisel repo.